Problem with decoding BinLogStreamReader. mysql python replication
I am using the following code in python to see the Mysql binlog.
#!/usr/bin/env python

#

# Update a redis server cache when an evenement is trigger
# in MySQL replication l

from pymysqlreplication import BinLogStreamReader
from pymysqlreplication.row_event import (
    DeleteRowsEvent,
    UpdateRowsEvent,
    WriteRowsEvent,
)

MYSQL_SETTINGS = {"host": "", "port": , "user": "", "passwd":""}


def main():

 stream = BinLogStreamReader(
    connection_settings=MYSQL_SETTINGS,
    server_id=100,  # server_id is your slave identifier, it should be unique
    only_events=[DeleteRowsEvent, WriteRowsEvent, UpdateRowsEvent],
    blocking=True,
    resume_stream=True

)
 for binlogevent in stream:
    prefix = (
        f"{binlogevent.schema}:"
        f"{binlogevent.table}:"
      )
 for row in binlogevent.rows:
        if isinstance(binlogevent, DeleteRowsEvent):
            vals = row["values"]
            print("\n")
            print(prefix + str(vals))
        elif isinstance(binlogevent, UpdateRowsEvent):
            vals = row
            print("\n")
            print(prefix + str(vals))
        elif isinstance(binlogevent, WriteRowsEvent):
            print("\n")
            vals = row["values"]
            print(prefix + str(vals))

 stream.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
main()

For most database tables it works correctly. But there is a table that has an encrypted column and it generates the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/test2.py", line 52, in <module>
    main()
  File "/root/test2.py", line 34, in main
    for row in binlogevent.rows:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pymysqlreplication/row_event.py", line 565, in rows
    self._fetch_rows()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pymysqlreplication/row_event.py", line 560, in _fetch_rows
    self.__rows.append(self._fetch_one_row())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pymysqlreplication/row_event.py", line 621, in _fetch_one_row
    row["values"] = self._read_column_data(self.columns_present_bitmap)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pymysqlreplication/row_event.py", line 148, in _read_column_data
    values[name] = self.__read_values_name(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pymysqlreplication/row_event.py", line 223, in __read_values_name
    return self.__read_string(column.length_size, column)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pymysqlreplication/row_event.py", line 335, in __read_string
    string = string.decode(errors=decode_errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa6 in position 0: invalid start byte

In the database the row is like this:

The idea is to be able to read that row and then decrypt.

Try repr(vals)  instead of str(vals).
